# Как закрыть iframe через 5 секунд?

Tags: fancybox, iframe

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как закрыть iframe через 5 секунд после открытия?
Всплывающие окна реализованы через fancybox.

Answer (score 1):

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/78qywns8/)**:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterLoad: function() {
        setTimeout(function(){$.fancybox.close();}, 5000);
    }
});
```